# How can I click elements inside Dash Tooltip?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a scatter plot graph and a `dcc.Tooltip` which shows over points on hover, similar to the examples [here](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/tooltip).

I want to add some interactive components within the tooltip, e.g. a button, but I cannot click anything within the tooltip. I can't even highlight text. It seems I just click through the tooltip and interact with the graph behind it.

Is there a way to interact with components inside a `dcc.Tooltip`?

Comment: Odd that this question received so little attention. I expect you need a persistent div that's toggled on clicking data points rather than one that renders only on hover.

Comment: I tried using a click callback so that the tooltip would not disappear when I moused away, however I still could not interact with the tooltip. I ended up moving the contents of the tooltip to a div beside the plot.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a simple dcc.Tooltip with css style set like this: `'pointer-events': 'auto'`. If you don't need to be able to place the tooltip at an arbitrary position with the `bbox` property, you can also use a dbc.Tooltip and attach it to any dash component in your app via the `target` property. With the dbc.Tooltip there is no need to adjust the css style.